# Display Items in observable collection as circular linked list

Tags: c#, wpf, collections, observablecollection

I have a Observable collection filled by items and a button, these items ordered descending by their ID

```
ocItems = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
IQueryable<Item> Query = _context.Item.OrderByDescending(s=>s.ItemID);
ocItems = new ObservableCollection<Item>(Query );
```

I want to display information for each item in each click in below way:

> The first click display Item1 infomation, the secound click display
>   the Item2 information .... The fifth click display the Item5
>   information, **The sixth click display the Item1 information** .. and
>   so on.

How can I display Items in observable collection as circular linked list?
when I display the second Item, how can I out the first item in the end of list?

Hope this clear

Comment: How about `list[clickCount % list.length]`?

Comment: How are you populating the observable collection

Comment: @TheGeneral ocItmes = new ObservableCollection<Item>(Query);

Comment: DataStructure which you described is not a Queue, it is more like Circular linked list. To loop items from an ordinary collection, keep record of current displayed index, increment it on each click and when reach the end, reset index to 0. no sorting is necessary

Comment: @ASh Thanks, I update my question title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply reset your index operator value [back to zero](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GSxcER):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var items = new []
        {
            new Item{ Id = 1, Value = "Hello" },
            new Item{ Id = 2, Value = "World!" },
        };

        var collection = new ObservableCollection<Item>(items);

        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            var item = collection[i % collection.Count];
            var message = String.Format("{0}: {1}", item.Id, item.Value);
            Console.WriteLine(message);
        }
    }
}

public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I want to display one item in each click, and the secound in the next click ... so on

Comment: @AbdulsalamElsharif: Then rename `i` to `clickCount` and increase the value in `onButtonClicked()`. Don't expect to get the full solution to your exact problem. This answer shows you how to cycle through a list when your index value is higher than the list count. How and when you use this information is your job.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `Tag` of each item to the index of the property; like:

```
//on click event:
(sender as TextBlock).Tag = ((int)((sender as TextBlock).Tag) + 1 ) % MAX;
```

or:

```
//on click command:
item.currentPropertyIndex = (item.currentPropertyIndex + 1 ) % MAX;
```

---

And then retrieve the target value using reflection or a method (`GetPropertyValueAt`) in `Item` class:

```
public string GetPropertyValueAt(int index)
{
     switch(index % MAX)
     {
          //default:
          //return prop1;
     }
}
```

or:

```
public string GetPropertyValueAt(int index)
{
    this.GetType().GetProperties()[index % MAX];
}
```

if your `Item` is a linked list, then:

```
public string GetPropertyValueAt(int index)
{
    return this.ElementAt(index % MAX);
}
```

---

Then add `Tag` to the binding of each item:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ocItems}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock>
                <TextBlock.Text>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource propSelector}">
                        <Binding Path=./>
                        <Binding Path="Tag" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}/>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </TextBlock.Text>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Using a converter, you can create your custom functionality for the binding:

```
public class PropSelector : IMultiValueConverter  
{  
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)  
    {  
        if (values != null)  
        {  
            return (values[0] as Item).GetPropertyValueAt(values[1]);  
        }  
        return "";  
    }  

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)  
    {  
        return null;  
    }  
}
```

Don't forget to add the converter to the window's resources.

Note that usage of `% MAX` is duplicated to ensure circular behaviour in any scenario.

Comment: @Bjan Thanks for your answer, l think Oliver answer is more simple.